# Intermittent NullPointerException with xe:dialog

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I've used the xe:dialog in many apps before just fine, but am having problems with a new XPage workflow form that has several buttons which call xe:dialog prompts.

As I test this with several browsers, with different logins to simulate an initiator and approvers, the buttons  works fine.  Then after a while, clicking one of these same buttons causes "Unexpected runtime error:  The runtime has encountered an unexpected error. java.lang.NullPointerException" -- from this point on, no user can click any of the buttons which use xe:dialog - they get the same error.  It is so messed up on the server that I have to restart HTTP or the whole server to get them working again.

During the workflow, the app sends emails with a link back to the XPage.  It seems like the problem occurs most frequently after the app has been opened with a link from an email (and the user has logged in).

So, some object is not being set properly.  How can I identify which object is not set?

Here's the trace

```
11/21/14 8:28 AM: Exception Thrown
Context Path: /aaa.nsf
Page Name: /test.xsp
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:865)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dynamiccontent.UIDynamicControl.invokeOnComponent(UIDynamicControl.java:254)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dialog.UIDialog.invokeOnComponent(UIDialog.java:543)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.invokeOnComponent(UIViewRootEx.java:1552)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._invokePartialRefresh(UIViewRootEx.java:1323)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx2._invokePartialRefresh(UIViewRootEx2.java:132)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1309)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:224)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dynamiccontent.AbstractDynamicContent.createContent(AbstractDynamicContent.java:134)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dialog.UIDialog$PopupContent.encodeBegin(UIDialog.java:224)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx$1.invokeContextCallback(UIViewRootEx.java:1326)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:862)
... 46 more
```

Comment: Could be worth looking at the code referenced in the error. AbstractDynamicContent (line 134) - https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/a915a03b169253ecfa1228ac860ab39e26a13881/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls/src/com/ibm/xsp/extlib/component/dynamiccontent/AbstractDynamicContent.java ,
UIDialog (line 224) - https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/a915a03b169253ecfa1228ac860ab39e26a13881/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls/src/com/ibm/xsp/extlib/component/dialog/UIDialog.java

Comment: Brian - thanks for the info.  Man, troubleshooting this gets way deeper than I would prefer to have dig,  but anyway AbstractDynamicContent line 134 is  ViewStateBean.get().initFromState();   and UIDialog line 224 is createContent(ctx);      not sure what to make of this besides the view state is messed up.

Comment: Ordinarily I'd dig into it a bit, but afraid I don't have the time at the moment. Some other kind soul may swoop in. But at the least I wanted you to be aware that the source code is now publicly available and easy to access on Github (only went up this week on Git)

Comment: Thanks - Just using Mark L's debug toolbar and can see that when I open the site from the URL in the browser that the applicationScope shows the viewStateBean initialized,  but when opening it from a link in an email the viewStateBean does not exist.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been a tough one to troubleshoot because of the intermittent nature of the errors and vague error message text.  I do not have a definitive answer, but it now appears to be working consistently without error after making two changes - so, I am documenting them so that it may possibly help point someone else towards a solution if they are getting NullPointerException related to xe:dialog.

First, I narrowed the error to occurring ONLY after opening the web app from a link sent in a notification email from the app:  the link url included "&action=openDocument" but needed to have "&action=editDocument" because the dialog has editable fields.

The second change was that the app had been getting data from a database that the user did not have ACL rights to access by using sessionAsSigner.  I've changed the ACL to allow the user access and changed the code from using sessionAsSigner to session.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the dialogbox is sitting inside a panel then in some conditions is not being rendered.  Remember you can't open something that doesn't exist.  Since you've used dialog boxes before and it looks like you're using dynamicContent...  that we be my first guess as to the problem.

Comment: thanks David -  all ideas are appreciated.  The weird thing is the dialogs work fine, until the pages are accessed from a link in an email.  The Debug Toolbar shows there is a applicationScope var "viewStateBean" when it is working correctly, but non-existent when accessed from an email link, and the dialogs no longer work for any users. It's like it has corrupted an object used by the application.